# Code block in gradle.processResources conditional on whether another task was requested

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We have an optional gradle task `docker` that depends on task `war`, which if executed, needs a war file generated with an extra file in it. This extra file can be added to the resources within the `processResources` task (or potentially directly in the `war` task). However, the corresponding code block must not run if task `docker` has not been requested and will not be run.

We need a **correct condition** in the following block checking if task `docker` is in the pipeline:

```
processResources {
  if (/* CONDITION HERE: task docker is requested */) {
    from ("${projectDir}/docker") {
      include "app.properties"
    }
  }
}

task docker(type: Dockerfile) {
  dependsOn build
  ...
```

**Clarification**: `processResources` is a standard dependency of the `war` task and the latter is a standard dependency of the `build` task. `processResources` is always executed on `build`, with or without the `docker` task to collect resources for assembling the war and may not be fully disabled in this case. One could move the code in question to a separate task dependent on `docker` and working on the output directory of `processResources`, yet before `war` is run, however, such a construct will result in much less clarity for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add additional dependency to your `docker` task, to make it relying not only on `build` task, but also on `processResources`. In that case, your `processResources` task will be called only if `docker` should be executed.

Another solution is to use [TaskExecutionGraph](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html). This let you initialize some variable, which could tell you, whether or not some task will be executed. But you have to understand, that graph is prepared only after all the configuration is done and you can rely on it only during the execution phase. Here is a short example, how it could be used:

```
//some flag, whether or not some task will be executed
def variable = false

//task with some logic executed during the execution phase
task test1 << {
    if (variable) {
        println 'task2 will be executed'
    } else {
        println 'task2 will not be executed'
    }
}

//according to whether or not this task will run or not, 
//will differs test1 task behavior
task test2(dependsOn: test1) {

}

//add some logic according to task execution graph
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    taskGraph ->
        //check the flag and execute only if it's true
        if (taskGraph.hasTask(test2)) {
            variable = true
            println 'task test2 will be executed'
        }
}
```

Furthermore, you can try to configure your custom task to make it disabled by setting is enabled property to false, if `docker` task is not in the execution graph. In that case you don't have to provide some flags and logic in execution phase. Like:

```
task test1 {       
    //some logic for execution
    doLast {
        println "execute some logic"
    }
}

task test2(dependsOn: test1) {

}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    taskGraph ->
        if (!taskGraph.hasTask(test2)) {
            //Disable test1 task if test2 will not run
            test1.enabled = false
        }
}
```

But it'll be impossible to run this custom task separately without some additional configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please check it against the correction I added to my question following your hints and update if necessary. If I understand correctly, the most elegant solution to keep the task and only make the code block conditional is to use a flag initialised via the TaskExecutionGraph. Will try and let know.

Comment: @Oleg there is one problem with the flag, it is available just in execution phase, but your task is pretty like a Copy task and the logic you provide is executed in configuration phase. I suppose, according to your clarification in updated question, the best solution is to split it into 2 task and disable one of them after the graph is ready, as it was done in the last example. Just don't forget to leave a comment above the task, that it should be possibly disabled somewhere else. Sure, if you are able to move your logic into execution phase, flag is the solution